# 301 redirect from one domain to another - what to do in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect

I have a Wordpress site in Network mode, using subdomains.

I had a site indexed as subdomain.example.com.

I recently purchased a domain, example2.com say.

Using the plugin "WordPress MU Domain Mapping". I remapped subdomain.example.com to example2.com.  The plugin performs a 301 redirect.

Google Webmaster Tools gave me a message saying it could no longer access subdomain.example.com.

I have created a new GWT website profile for example2.com.

I used a server redirect checker, and subdomain.example.com/* is being redirected to example2.com/*

I have 3 questions:

1. Both subdomain.example.com & example2.com are returned in the SERP when I search for my site name.  Should I delete subdomain.example.com from the index?  Will this delete the link juice that subdomain.example.com will pass on to example2.com?
2. What do I do with the GWT profile for subdomain.example.com?  Do I delete it?
3. I guess I have to wait for the PR of example2.com to increase from 0?  (subdomain.example.com has a PR of 4)

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both subdomain.example.com & example2.com are returned in the SERP
>   when I search for my site name. Should I delete subdomain.example.com
>   from the index? Will this delete the link juice that
>   subdomain.example.com will pass on to example2.com?

No, do not delete subdomain.example.com. If you do so, all your link juice will be lost. As you are aleady doing 301 redirect, the link juice and rankings will pass onto your new domain. It takes time.

> What do I do with the GWT profile for subdomain.example.com? Do I
>   delete it?

There is no harm in leaving it as it is. Deleting it also shouldn't cause any problem.

> I guess I have to wait for the PR of example2.com to increase from 0?
>   (subdomain.example.com has a PR of 4)

Yes, you need to wait for the next PR update. However, Google continuously updates its internal PR. The toolbar PR is updated only occassionally. The internal PR is the one that Google uses as a ranking factor. ( one of the many factors )

Comment: Will it take some time for subdomain.example.com to be removed from the SERP, now that a 301 redirect to example2.com is in place?